# Button pressed color, how can I use default whether on 4.4 or previous?

Tags: android

My understanding is that 4.4 changed some of the highlight colors for buttons to be grey or more neutral rather than blue. In my app I have some buttons which are a custom drawable - just a shape with rounded corners and then a selector for all the states.  Now in my app so far I have just hard coded actual colors in this selector which are the same as from the default Holo theme on 4.0-4.3.  However, with this recent change I want the pressed state of these buttons to be default (grey) when ran on 4.4+ devices.  This way they will match the action bar highlights etc.

So far I have tried to use attribute 'colorPressedHighlight' in my selector but this doesn't work (I don't fully understand attributes/styles to be honest).  The app wont compile, seemingly you can't refer to an attribute in place of a color.

Is there a way to do this?  I'm now thinking maybe a different selector for each API version and just hard code the values in each? From a brief look I think this is possible, seems very inelegant though.  This really shouldn't be as hard as it seems, right?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> res / values-v19

Create value folder for **API level 19 i.e for android 4.4** and above.

```
res/values-v19/colors.xml
```

define custom color value for button selection color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color
        name="button_selection"
        >hex_color(Gray)</color>
</resources>
```

Create value folder for **API level below 19 i.e for below android 4.4**

> res/values/colors.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color
            name="button_selection"
            >hex_color(blue)</color>
    </resources>
```

Then use this value in your custom drawable.

Comment: This is probably the way to go and simpler than my alternative.  Not ideal but Android huh, thanks!